# Unable to create gcp vpc using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, gcp-vpc-firewall

I am trying to create VPC in GCP using Terraform but when i run terraform apply I am getting an error in terminal. I am new to terraform and GCP this is the code is have used

```
//Google Cloud provider
provider "google" {
 credentials = "${file("${var.credentials}")}"
 project     = "${var.gcp_project}"
 region      = "${var.region}"
}
// Create VPC
resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
 name                    = "${var.name}-vpc"
 auto_create_subnetworks = "false"
}

//variables.tf
variable "region" {}
variable "gcp_project" {}
variable "credentials" {}
variable "name" {}
variable "subnet_cidr" {}

// terraform.tfvars
region          = "europe-west2"
gcp_project     = "rock-prism-350316"
credentials     = "credentials.json"
name            = "dev"
subnet_cidr     = "10.10.0.0/24"
```

I am using a service account which has below access :
Editor access for project, admin compute network

```
Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

google_compute_network.vpc_network: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Error creating Network: Post 
"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/rock-prism-350316/global/networks? 
alt=json": oauth2: cannot fetch token: unexpected EOF
│
│   with google_compute_network.vpc_network,
│   on main.tf line 8, in resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network":
│    8:     resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
```

Comment: Looking at the code, I suspect the `credentials` line in the `provider` block.  Looking here ... https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#credentials

It seems to want to be a file name.  Your logic seems to be reading the content of the file.  Try:

`credentials = "${var.credentials}"` assuming that var.credentials contains the path to the JSON file

Comment: I gave the path and provided this change but it does not work

Comment: When you say it did not work ... did the message change or any other symptom change?

Comment: The error message still has not changed.

Comment: Is billing for the project setup? Is the account disabled?

Comment: Yes I am able to create other resource

Comment: Maybe describe how you populated or obtained the credentials.json file?  I am hesitant to ask you to post what you find in there for obvious security reasons (no-one should ever ask you to post credentials or passwords in this community).  I'm wondering if the content of the file has been copy/pasted or has somehow otherwise been corrupted?  Knowing how you sourced it in the first place might show us a clue.

Comment: I can try with a new service account would that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was there a security software installed on my device and that was blocking the communication between GCP provider and terraform. I had to disable this from services once that was done it was working fine. There was no issues in code or in authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **contents** of a key file **or** a file path in the provider (see [credentials section](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#credentials)).
The error message you're getting shows that it's trying to create a network in project `rock-prism-350316` using credentials for project `sunlit-vortex-184612`

Try correcting the `gcp_project` value in your tfvars file. It's also a good idea to add the `project` parameter to your VPC resource:

```
//Google Cloud provider
provider "google" {
 credentials = "${file("${var.credentials}")}"
 project     = "${var.gcp_project}"
 region      = "${var.region}"
}
// Create VPC
resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
 name                    = "${var.name}-vpc"
 project                 = "${var.gcp_project}"
 auto_create_subnetworks = "false"
}

//variables.tf
variable "region" {}
variable "gcp_project" {}
variable "credentials" {}
variable "name" {}
variable "subnet_cidr" {}

// terraform.tfvars
region          = "europe-west2"
gcp_project     = "rock-prism-350316"
credentials     = "credentials.json"
name            = "dev"
subnet_cidr     = "10.10.0.0/24"
```

Comment: That is the name of the project which you are a part of. I can only see rock-prism-350316 in my google cloud console.

Comment: No, I don't have projects named rock-prism-350316 or sunlit-vortex-184612. Look again at the gcp_project value in your terraform.tfvars file posted in your question. You are loading credentials for one project and trying to use them to create resources in a different project.

Comment: I tried this out now am getting another error. which is       │ Error: Error when reading or editing Project Service rock-prism-350316/compute.googleapis.com: Get "https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/rock-prism-350316?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": oauth2: cannot fetch token: unexpected EOF

Comment: Check the contents of your credentials.json file. The third line should have the project ID rock-prism-350316 in it. If it's different then you're trying to use a key file from a different project, maybe an old project that you've deleted. If that's the case then create a new key for your service account and replace credentials.json with it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer to take it into account.

Comment: Still shows the same error. can u suggest what all roles i should map to the service account that i create ? Maybe it does not have proper access

Comment: Again, it isn't being caused by missing roles. When that happens you get 403 errors which usually include the permission / role required. I suggest following the quickstart at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started