# Unable to create GCP resource using terraform apply although service account has required permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to follow the tutorial here https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/gcp-get-started/google-cloud-platform-build . I believe I've included all necessary information in this post, but **please let me know if there's anything else I could add :)**.

*(The linked tutorial could be ignored and the question interpreted as "I'm getting the following error from this main.tf file with these permissions, how do I fix", but the tutorial probably gives some more context)*

### Console error

I'm getting the following error from `terraform-apply`:

```bash
# terraform apply

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # google_compute_network.vpc_network will be created
  + resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
      + auto_create_subnetworks         = true
      + delete_default_routes_on_create = false
      + gateway_ipv4                    = (known after apply)
      + id                              = (known after apply)
      + internal_ipv6_range             = (known after apply)
      + mtu                             = (known after apply)
      + name                            = "terraform-network"
      + project                         = (known after apply)
      + routing_mode                    = (known after apply)
      + self_link                       = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

google_compute_network.vpc_network: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Error creating Network: googleapi: Error 403: Permission denied on resource project terraform-learning-311890>.
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
│     "links": [
│       {
│         "description": "Google developer console API key",
│         "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/terraform-learning-311890\u003e/apiui/credential"
│       }
│     ]
│   },
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│     "domain": "googleapis.com",
│     "metadatas": {
│       "consumer": "projects/terraform-learning-311890\u003e",
│       "service": "compute.googleapis.com"
│     },
│     "reason": "CONSUMER_INVALID"
│   }
│ ]
│ , forbidden
│
│   with google_compute_network.vpc_network,
│   on main.tf line 30, in resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network":
│   30: resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
```

### `main.tf`

Apparently my `main.tf` file is consistent:

```bash
user@comp ~/D/p/learn-terraform-gcp [1]> terraform validate
Success! The configuration is valid.
```

My `main.tf` file is:

```
# I have changed the region and zone values from those in the tutorial to match
# the output from the following:

# gcloud config list compute/region
# gcloud config list compute/zone
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "4.51.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  credentials = file("./terraform-learning-311890-692452ead201.json")
  project     = "terraform-learning-311890>"
  region      = "europe-west2-c"
  zone        = "europe-west2-c"
}

resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
  name = "terraform-network"
}
```

### service account json file

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "terraform-learning-311890",
  "private_key_id": " ... ",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
  ...
  -----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "terraform-gcp-testing@terraform-learning-311890.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "...",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/terraform-gcp-testing%40terraform-learning-311890.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

### service account permissions

Permissions assigned to the service account I'm using (note `editor`, which is the only permission stated to be necessary in the tutorial):

```
# gcloud projects get-iam-policy terraform-learning-311890

bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:terraform-gcp-testing@terraform-learning-311890.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/editor
- members:
  - user:user@gmail.com
  role: roles/owner
etag: UwX39XyPWEX=
version: 1
```

---

I have viewed suggested post [unable to create gcp vpc using terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72319346/unable-to-create-gcp-vpc-using-terraform) but don't feel that it is the same as this.

### Edit

After changing my project id to remove the `>` as explained I got the following error from `terraform apply`:

```
│ Error: Error creating Network: googleapi: Error 403: Compute Engine API has not been used in project ... before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/compute.googleapis.com/overview?project=... then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
...
```

Visiting the given URL given, enbling the Compute API then re-running `terraform apply` resulted in:

```
...

google_compute_network.vpc_network: Creating...
google_compute_network.vpc_network: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
google_compute_network.vpc_network: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
google_compute_network.vpc_network: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
google_compute_network.vpc_network: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
google_compute_network.vpc_network: Creation complete after 43s [id=projects/terraform-learning-381816/global/networks/terraform-network]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just kept the project ID with an extra ">" at the end.
Please correct your project ID.

That is the problem. A service Account with an Editor role can create a VPC.

```
provider "google" {
 credentials = file("./terraform-learning-311890-692452ead201.json")
 project     = "terraform-learning-311890"
 region      = "europe-west2-c"
 zone        = "europe-west2-c"
```

}

Comment: oh no - what a stupid mistake :S I had to enable the Compute API - then it worked, thank you!